# If-statement in update function running twice python

Tags: python

I am writing a tile matching game in pygame. I have a tile class and a board class, the board class has a tiles instance variable that is a list of tiles. This is my mainloop

```py
def main() -> None:
    board = Board()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
        (board.rows*TILE_SIZE, board.cols*TILE_SIZE))
    
    ...
    while True:
        ...
        pos = None
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            ...
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                pos = event.pos

        screen.fill(WHITE)
        board.update(screen, pos)
        pygame.display.flip()
```

The board.uptade which updates each tile click and then draws it to the screen. if the tile is cliked, add it to the answer list

```py
def update(self, screen: Surface, pos: tuple[int, int]) -> None:
    for tile in self.tiles:
        if tile.update_click(pos) and tile.enabled:
            self.answer_list.append(tile)
            self.handle_click()
         tile.draw(screen)
```

When i check the board.answer_list, each tile seems to be added twice. When i check how many times the for-loop in board.update is running by printing the current tile each time, i get the correct amount of tiles. But when i print the current tile in the if-statement, i get the same tile which i click on twice. Why is this happening
tile.update_click, which checks if the tile has been cliked

```py
    def update_click(self, pos: tuple[int, int]) -> bool:
        if pos and self.is_clicked(pos) and not self.clicked and self.enabled:
            self.clicked = True
        return self.clicked
```

Comment: It's not clear what happens in your event main loop,, are you sure the `pos` variable in the line `board.update(screen, pos)` is not getting stale values? Also, what if-statement are you referring to when you say > But when i print the current tile in the if-statement

Comment: The if statement in the board.update function. the pos variable is the current position of the mouse, it may be none if the user has not clicked

Comment: Have you checked for duplicate tiles?  Two tiles with the same values that *appear* like a double-up.

Comment: The board.tiles only contains unique tiles

Comment: What does the `self.handle_click` method do?

Comment: It checks the answer list if it has two items then it checks if  both items have same text and updates accordingly